# Issues with basic pie chart display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, pie-chart

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/et8Dwa?p=preview) on Plunker.

I have <s>2</s> 1 issues, <s>when there are 3 or more slices in the pie, it looks like there is a little sliver that is not filled in</s>. The other is if there are less than 3 slices in the pie, it looks all wonky.

Looks like the wonky happens when a slice is over 50% of the pie (StephenH comment below).

This is the bit of code that fills in the slices based on an array `$scope.viewData` is a simple array, `[1,2,3]` for example. The `$scope.viewDataTotal` variable is the sum of the array values, `6` for the shown example array.

```
    $scope.updateView = function () {
      if ($scope.viewData) {
        var svg = $element.children('svg');
        svg.empty();

        var cX = $element.width() / 2;
        var cY = $element.height() / 2;
        var r = cX;
        if (cY < r) {
          r = cY;
        }
        r -= 5;
        if (r < 0) {
          r = 0;
        }

        var sd = 0;
        var idxColor = 0;
        $scope.viewData.forEach(function(i) {
          var degrees = i / $scope.viewDataTotal * 360;

          var p = '<path d="';
          p += generateWedgeString(cX, cY, sd, sd + degrees, r);
          p += '" fill="';
          p += $scope.colors[idxColor];
          p +='" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" />';

          svg.append(jQuery(p));
          sd += degrees;
          idxColor++;
        });

        $element.html($element.html());
      }
    };
```

The math bit is in the `generateWedgeString` function:

```
var generateWedgeString = function(startX, startY, startAngle, endAngle, radius){
  var x1 = startX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * startAngle/180);
  var y1 = startY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * startAngle/180);
  var x2 = startX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle/180);
  var y2 = startY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle/180);

  var pathString = "M"+ startX + "," + startY + " L" + x1 + "," + y1 + " A" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0,1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z";

  return pathString;
};
```

*update*:
Dave's answer works but it introduces other issues. For example You can see the divider between each 1/2 of the slice. Another would be I can't easily do mouse over events.

Comment: Why are you using `var degrees = i / $scope.viewDataTotal * 359;` instead of `var degrees = i / $scope.viewDataTotal * 360;`? Changing that number to 360 makes the sliver issue go away...

Comment: Also, the bug is more general than just _if there are less than 3 slices in the pie, it looks all wonky._. It actually looks _wonky_ if you have a slice that is greater than 50% of the pie. You can verify this by trying [1,1] or [2,2]

Comment: @StephenH - awesome. I used 359 cause I though 0 to 356 was 360 degrees. I've updated the code to use 360 and the little sliver issue goes away. Just the wonky issue left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will be because you are not setting the large-arc-sweep flag to 1 in your path string when a slice is greater than 50%.

Please see this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and search for "large-arc-sweep-flag".

Additionally have a look at the piechart directive I have written [here](http://crudbetter.github.io/angular-charts/) and [here](https://github.com/crudbetter/angular-charts) that demonstrates how to use it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but a kind of hacky work around, is to see if the wedge is more than half of the total, if so, cut the wedge in half, and do it twice with the same color:

```
if (i > ($scope.viewDataTotal/2)) {
    tmp = true;
    degrees/=2;
 }
 var p = '<path d="';
 p += generateWedgeString(cX, cY, sd, sd+degrees, r);
 p += '" fill="';
 p += $scope.colors[idxColor];
 p +='" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" />';
 if (tmp) {
     sd = sd + degrees;
     p += '<path d="';
     p += generateWedgeString(cX, cY, sd, sd+degrees, r);
     p += '" fill="';
     p += $scope.colors[idxColor];
     p +='" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" />';
     tmp=false;
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vuoN94nYqv4uZh4ygdhx?p=preview